# URL package installed but cannot be found by pdflatex

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, packages, texlive, urls

I recently installed a full version of `TeXLive 2012` (around 3.2 GB installation). Following is a simple `LaTeX` code that I am unable to compile:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{\LaTeX\ Document}
\author{Joe the Student}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   Hello world!
   My email is \href{mailto:my_email@server.org}{my\_email@server.org}
\end{document}
```

I get following error when I try to compile with `pdflatex`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tex.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)

! LaTeX Error: File `url.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(./tex.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./tex.out) (./tex.out) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./tex.aux)  

*File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
hyperref.sty    2012/05/13 v6.82q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/05/13 v6.82q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2012/05/13 v6.82q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
     tex.out
     tex.out
 ***********

)</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr1
    0.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><
    /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
    Output written on tex.pdf (1 page, 34458 bytes).
    Transcript written on tex.log.
```

Compilation halts at the prompt:

```
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

and then proceeds and **does create** the pdf as expected.
However I don't understand why I get the compilation error in the first place.

I **successfully verified** that packages `hyperref` and `url` are installed using command:

```
tlmgr show <pkg-name>
```

However, I read somewhere that `url` is part of `ltxmisc` and output of

```
ls /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ltxmisc/
```

has `url.sty` missing.

Please let me know what could be wrong.

Comment: Your pdftex says "Debian" at the start. Are you sure that it is from the fresh Texlive and not from another TeX?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I installed `TexLive 2012` fresh this morning using `install-tl` script. I am using `Ubuntu`, that's why may be output of `pdflatex` mentions `Debian`.

Comment: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: Sorry but I doubt that the log is from a fresh Texlive. E.g. The hyperref version looks to old.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You are correct. I had installed

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You are correct. I had installed 'Gummi', a `LaTeX` editor that must have installed all the other dependencies to compile and view `LaTeX` documents. I checked I have `latex` in `/usr/bin/` that must have been installed by `Gummi` or some other program`. `/usr/bin/` is earlier in `PATH` than `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux`, hence it was picking up `pdflatex` from the earlier path.

However, what I am surprised by is that I never installed `texlive` from `synaptic/software center`. How come even the basic document got compiled?

Answer (score 5):

`url.sty` is part of TeX Live package `url` and is installed as

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
```

If the file is present, it should be listed in

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R
```

with the two lines:

```
./tex/latex/url:
url.sty
```

If not, then regenerate `ls-R` by running `texhash /usr/share/texlive` as user `root`
(as user that has permissions for `/usr/share/texlive/`).

If the file `url.sty` is missing in this location, then you can try

```
$ find /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ -name url.sty
```

to locate it.

### Manual installation

[CTAN:macros/latex/contrib/url/](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/) contains the files for package `url`. They should be sorted into the following `texmf`/`TDS` locations:

TDS:doc/latex/url/miscdoc.sty
 TDS:doc/latex/url/url.pdf
 TDS:doc/latex/url/url.tex
 TDS:tex/latex/url/url.sty

Usually additional packages are installed in the local or home `texmf` tree. In this case, however, it would put them into the distribution tree:

TDS: ≡ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/

The run `texhash` again.

I do not know your, why your full install misses the `url` package or why it cannot be reinstalled. Enable verbose/debug options for `tlmgr` if available and post the output,
perhaps someone can see the reason. There is also a mailing list [`texlive`](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live) for problems/bug reports regarding `tlmgr`.

Comment: I regenerated `ls-R`, however the output of `find` command is still empty. `ls-R` after regeneration does not contain the two lines you mentioned.

BTW, I freshly installed `TexLive 2012` **this** morning.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni Can you reinstall the package?

Comment: @HeikoOverdiek: I tried that as well using command `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall url`, however no success.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni I have added a section for manual installation, because I am not an expert for `tlmgr`. And without its output, logs, there is not much information to work with.

Comment: File `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty` exists
File `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R contains` 
./tex/latex/aurl:
aurl.sty
But I have the error `href.sty` not found.
And I do not find this file indeed - how to fix?